# Hide icons and other in status bar Android

Tags: android, hide, statusbar, android-icons

I should prefer to totaly hide the bottom status bar in android tablet (Androide 3.x and 4.x), but it seems to be impossible, because the new android version removed the physical keybutton from devices. Therefore I would at least remove from the bottom status bar, the clock, battery icon, and others. I only want the "Back", "Home" and "Options" buttons. It's possible?

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html#considerations-split-action-bars In tablet devices, when set Full screen mode, the BottomBar and notification bar (including clock and other) are merged. I practically want hide the notification bar side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Therefore I would at least remove from the bottom status bar, the clock, battery icon, and others. I only want the "Back", "Home" and "Options" buttons. It's possible?

If you make your own ROM mod with your own modified build of Android, yes. An SDK application cannot remove items from the system bar.

Comment: Until Android 2.3, I could get with full screen mode, the entire display. It's no more possible, because there are no more the physical keys, but I don't see any reason to keep the notification bar in all apps, therefore I suppose exists a way to hide it.

Comment: @Eghes: On API Level 14+, you may be able to use `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION` to hide the system bar temporarily, but it will return when the user interacts with the screen, based on the docs (I have not tried this flag yet). Otherwise, AFAIK, you cannot remove the system bar on tablets, only on phones. And, your question was not about hiding the bar, but actually changing its contents, which is not possible outside of firmware.

Comment: Ok, I hoped there was a way to hide at least the clock icon. I'm developing a peculiar application which need to prevent the user can go out from application Activities, except with the ways I established inside the application. The Clock in status bar allow to go in Android Settings, and I wanted to prevent it...

Comment: @Eghes: Since they could reboot their device in safe mode and remove your app, you would need to implement a custom ROM anyway.

Comment: Yes, but to start the device in safe mode, is required the will of user to break the device. But I need only to protect the device from inexpert users, which could accidentally damage the device, accessing to android settings(unwittingly).